# Nested json and dataframe - retrieving data from array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to retrieve data from json file.

```
df=spark.read.json('/home/data/activities.json',multiLine=True)
```

The content looks like this below (I include only 1 "data" row, there are 94):

```
{"meta.count":"94",
"data":[
{"id":"f67de4f6-d23e-49a7-b9dd-63d68df533a3",
"name.fi":"Purjehdus 1700-luvun tyyliin tykkisluuppi Dianalla","name.en":"Cannon sloop Diana\u00B4s sailings","name.sv":"Seglingar med kanonslupen Diana",
"name.zh":null,
"source_type.id":3,
"source_type.name":"MyHelsinki",
"info_url":"https:\/\/www.suomenlinnatours.com\/en\/cannon-sloop-diana?johku_product=7",
"modified_at":"2019-12-28T15:10:33.145Z",
"location.lat":60.145111083984375,
"location.lon":24.987560272216797,
"location.address.street_address":"Suomenlinna Tykist\u00F6lahti Pier",
"location.address.postal_code":null,
"location.address.locality":"Helsinki",
"description.intro":null,
"description.body":"<p>Luvassa on amiraali Chapamin tahdittama mielenkiintoinen laivamatka valistusajan Viaporiin... /p>\r\n",
"description.images":[
{"url":"https:\/\/edit.myhelsinki.fi\/sites\/default\/files\/2017-06\/Tykkisluuppi_Diana.jpg",
 "copyright_holder":"",
 "license_type.id":1,
 "license_type.name":"All rights reserved."},
{"url":"https:\/\/edit.myhelsinki.fi\/sites\/default\/files\/2017-06\/Tykkisluuppi_Diana_2.jpg",
 "copyright_holder":"",
 "license_type.id":1,
 "license_type.name":"All rights reserved."},
{"url":"https:\/\/edit.myhelsinki.fi\/sites\/default\/files\/2017-06\/Tykkisluuppi_Diana_3.jpg",
 "copyright_holder":"",
 "license_type.id":1,"license_type.name":"All rights reserved."}],
"tags":[
 {"id":"myhelsinki:45","name":"sea"},
 {"id":"myhelsinki:836","name":"suomenlinna"},
 {"id":"myhelsinki:793","name":"history"}],
"where_when_duration.where_and_when":"Suomenlinna, kes\u00E4kuusta elokuuhun",
"where_when_duration.duration":"N. 1h 45min"}],
"tags":[
 {"id":"myhelsinki:453","name":"nature"},
 {"id":"myhelsinki:747","name":"canoeing"},
 {"id":"myhelsinki:342","name":"guidance"},
 {"id":"myhelsinki:399","name":"outdoor recreation"}],
"where_when_duration.where_and_when":"Toukokuussa joka sunnuntai, kes\u00E4-elokuussa joka keskiviikko ja sunnuntai, syyskuussa joka sunnuntai",
"where_when_duration.duration":"4,5 tuntia sis\u00E4lt\u00E4en kuljetuksen"}],

"tags.myhelsinki:10":"sauna",
"tags.myhelsinki:1016":"heavy rock",
"tags.myhelsinki:1749":"national parks",
"tags.myhelsinki:1822":"schools (educational institutions)",
"tags.myhelsinki:2":"food"
}
```

The schema looks as follows:

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- description.body: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description.images: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- copyright_holder: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- license_type.id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- license_type.name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description.intro: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- info_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location.address.locality: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location.address.postal_code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location.address.street_address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location.lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location.lon: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- modified_at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name.en: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name.fi: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name.sv: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name.zh: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- source_type.id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- source_type.name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- where_when_duration.duration: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- where_when_duration.where_and_when: string (nullable = true)
 |-- meta.count: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags.myhelsinki:10: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags.myhelsinki:1016: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags.myhelsinki:1749: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags.myhelsinki:1822: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags.myhelsinki:2: string (nullable = true)
```

I am interested in "data" array, including nested array "tags". I would like to skip "meta.count" and "tags.myhelsinki:..."

I tried this:

```
df.withColumn("expl_data", explode_outer(col("tags"))).select("expl_data.data.name.en").show(10)
```

and I get error message:

```
AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`tags`' given input columns: [tags.myhelsinki:10, tags.myhelsinki:453, tags.myhelsinki:226, tags.myhelsinki:1016, tags.myhelsinki:342, tags.myhelsinki:531, tags.myhelsinki:364, tags.myhelsinki:836, tags.myhelsinki:346,...
```

I have the same error when I try to explode "tags.name" or "description.images" arrays.
Could anyone please help? My goal is to retrieve a set of selected fields from this structure (tags are very important).

Many thanks in advance!
Alicia

Answer (score 0):

You have to explode the `data` array first so that you can access the nested fields:

```
df = df.select(explode_outer(col("data")).alias("data")).select(col("data.*"))
```

Now, you can explode the inner arrays `tags` and `description.images`like this:

```
df = df.withColumn("tags", explode_outer(col("tags")))\
       .withColumn("description.images", explode_outer(col("`description.images`")))
```

And finally select the columns you want:

```
df.select("id", "tags.name", "`name.en`").show()

+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
|                  id|       name|             name.en|
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
|f67de4f6-d23e-49a...|        sea|Cannon sloop Dian...|
|f67de4f6-d23e-49a...|        sea|Cannon sloop Dian...|
|f67de4f6-d23e-49a...|        sea|Cannon sloop Dian...|
|f67de4f6-d23e-49a...|suomenlinna|Cannon sloop Dian...|
|f67de4f6-d23e-49a...|suomenlinna|Cannon sloop Dian...|
|f67de4f6-d23e-49a...|suomenlinna|Cannon sloop Dian...|
|f67de4f6-d23e-49a...|    history|Cannon sloop Dian...|
|f67de4f6-d23e-49a...|    history|Cannon sloop Dian...|
|f67de4f6-d23e-49a...|    history|Cannon sloop Dian...|
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

Notice that some columns contain a dot in their name, use **``** to select them.